# Internal URL redirect to particular server and port

Tags: networking, redirect, port-forwarding

What is the easiest way or what options do I have in order to create an alternative internal URL on our network to access a particular internal website?

For example

I have just installed the Spiceworks ticketing application on port 9675 on a server that is also hosting the Terminal Services RDS application portal.

I have already set up a DNS A Record of rds to direct to this server by entering rds.domain.com/RDWeb.

How and where do I set up an address of for example http://helpdesk opposed to using http://servername:9675

This particular server has IIS installed and we have a Watchguard firewall, the dns server is installed on our domain controllers (not this particular server) OS is Server 2008 R2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do not create virtual host (resolved by name) for helpdesk. In such case you will need update of your hosts so rds.domain.com and helpdesk.domain.com direct to one IP

Comment: @Rld Was the answer I posted able to solve your problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) Add a new Host (A) record on your local DNS server to associate the hostname "helpdesk" with an IP address on some server which has IIS on it.

2) Set up a new site on that IIS and either assign that site a dedicated internal IP (which would need to match what you set in step 1), or if for some reason you'd prefer, you can do a shared internal IP (i.e. the same IP that another site on that IIS is using), but have the site listen for the HTTP host header of helpdesk and make sure the original site is the default for all other traffic on that IP so you don't break it.

3) Then for that IIS site you created, set it up to redirect to http://servername:9675, perhaps using some technique listed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430295/how-to-redirect-a-site-to-another-location-in-iis7

Another possibility is if you use OpenDNS, if I recall correctly they support setting up shortcuts like this, but I don't know how well it plays with having local Windows DNS setup.